# Hibernate Select count native query slow

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle10g

I have the native query (pseudocode): **SELECT count(1) FROM my_table WHERE conditions**

When I execute it in SQLDeveloper, the query takes about 2 seconds. But when it is executed in my application takes about 35 seconds. The code is:

```
String nativeSql = SELECT count(1) FROM my_table WHERE conditions;

Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(nativeSql);

int total = ((BigDecimal) query.getSingleResult()).intValue(); // Very Slow
```

The persistence.xml is configured as follow:

```
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
    </properties>
```

The results of statistics are: time: 35842ms, rows: 1

The table has a total of 567.885 registers, and the above query returns 134.736. I can't see what is the problem of the bad performace when it is a simple query.

Comment: Try to test it more thoroughly. Usually such query is slow on 1st execution. But is executed much faster when db blocks are cached. PS: of course I assume you execute exactly the same query having same conditions and the same exec plan using SQL Developer.

Comment: I launched the same query many times and the time is similar all time (both in my app as in SQL Developer). And yes, I take the query shown in console and I execute it as is in SQL Developer.

Comment: It seems that the table was fragmented by `delete` (it did not have permissions for a `truncate`). Oracle, internally, had to analyze and correct this problem. The `Select count` now works as it should.